# how to run this on Windows as it needs "source venv/bin/activate" and "flask run"

Tags: python, python-2.7, unix

I need to try to run this https://github.com/dhavalhparikh/werewolf_web_app

there are instructions - but they are for Linux/MacOS 
I am on Win10

I am stuck when I try to run

```
(venv) C:\PyCharm\QA_testing_419\venv\werewolf_web_app-master>source venv/bin/activate
'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

also when I try to do

```
(venv) C:\PyCharm\QA_testing_419\venv\werewolf_web_app-master>export FLASK_APP=run.py
'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

and

```
(venv) C:\PyCharm\QA_testing_419\venv\werewolf_web_app-master>flask run
'flask' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

any advice?

I am in PyCharm ... but can be in any IDE

Comment: Those commands are for a bash shell, but you are using cmd. I would install and use git bash.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try and help you if I can. (I'm also a beginner here!)

`source venv/bin/activate`

- On windows, you should look for the activate.bat file which should be inside the bin (Ooops, Scripts folder for windows) folder. You just have to run the activate.bat file not use source command.
- Edit : Inside the folder where you downloaded the app and created the venv, go to the venv folder, then to Scripts folder, then execute the "activate.bat" file. This should show that your virtual environment is active from the "(venv)" added before your drive and directory path. After this, go back to the app's root folder where requirements.txt is found then pip-install the requirements. (I tried it on my machine, I get install errors on Python 3.8 while installing requirements. Maybe it was written for Python 2.x?)

`export FLASK_APP=run.py`

- Again on windows, it's 'set FLASK_APP=run.py' not export

`flask run`

- If the two steps above have been done correctly (and without any install errors), above command should work.